# Celery RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery, scheduled-tasks

```
celery = Celery(
    __name__,
    broker=broker_url,
    backend=backend_url,
    beat_schedule=schedule,
    include=["tasks],
)

celery.config_from_object(config.get("config"))

celery.conf.update()

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    celery.start()
```

I have the tasks in beat_schedule. Some tasks i start through asyncio, like this:

```
async def main() -> None:
    await class().method()

@celery.task
def some_task() -> None:
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Usually I use not async function. But when I started to use asyncio, I have error **RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'**.
Anybody know why this happening?